# Navigate to a frame that havn't been used yet

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using Nativescript-Vue, and i encounter this problem. Actually we can use navigateTo and specify a frame that will hold our Page modules. My problem is that i can't navigate to an unused frame since navigateTo method is using tns-core-modules/ui/frame/getFrameById which only work for already navigated frames.

I will try to explain my issue : 
Actually, i use only one frame for all my application.
I have a Login page/component which is the entry point of my application in case of user is not auth.

After the login process, the user can access to the real application. The issue appears when he will logout : the majority of my components in my application are using data related to his account, so, when he disconnect, all these components are breaking up because these component, which are in NavigationEntry, are still in my "DOM" ( ? i don't know how i can name the "DOM" of nativescript ).

So i wanted to use a Frame for the Login process, and a frame for my Application, so, when the user logout, i can use navigateTo(Login, { clearHistory: true } in order to remove all the NavigationEntry that contains my components which are using the account's data.

And, that's where I wanted to come : in the case of the user is already authentificated when launching the app, the frame dedied for login havn't be used, so when the user press "logout" i can't navigate to this unused frame.

Here a little diagram of what i wanted to achieve :
[image]

Maybe there is a simpler way to clean all the navigation entry, but i didn't find how.

Maybe i poorly structured my project, so tell me if i'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Looking at your diagram, I assume you don't have nested navigation in your app therefore I think one root frame should be enough for you, when you go from Login to Home or from any page to Login, you just got to clear history.

Comment: Yes you are right. I figured out how to fix my issue after some thinkings. One frame will be sufisant.
I had some issues very specific to my projects so i think it's not important if i don't explain how i fixed this problem.

( in any case, in more complex scenario, i think the possibility of selecting an unused frame could be nice. According to my research, it isn't possible. If someone knows how we can do this, feel free to answer. )

Thanks !